# Icon after each value for specific column generated in PHP with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

What I want to do is that after each value an icon of a cup is shown. But that only for the 'Cups (In spanish Copas)' column of my 'Players' table.

The code for the table right now looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT Name, Copas FROM ggxxplayers.players ORDER by Copas DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die (mysqli_error($link));
echo "<table id=\"table3\";>\n";
while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little change to foreach and it will display image in 'copas' td (code does not check value,  it can be added to if statement):

```
foreach ($line as $col_name => $col_value) {
    echo "\t\t<td>$col_value";
    if ($col_name == 'copas') echo '<img src='link_to_your_img' />';
    echo '</td>\n';
}
```